# Servlet returning HTML

Tags: ajax, servlets

I am new to use AJAX methods. When the GET method is called, it sends a value as a parameter to the servlet which does the processing without a problem, but the `doGet(request, response)` returns the whole HTML code of the jsp instead of returning the string result which is in the shape of a JSON object.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#categoryProductID').change(function(event) {
    var cat=$("#categoryProductID").val();
    $.get('ServletController', {category:cat}, function(responseText){
      $('#subCategoryID').text(responseText);
    })
  })
});
```

On the hand here is the servlet `doGet` code:

```
String categoriId = request.getParameter("category");
if(categoriId != null && !categoriId.equals("")) {
  sousCategorieDao.listerParIdCategorie(Long.valueOf(categoriId))) {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(categoriId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi , what do you mean by `whole HTML code of the jsp..`.? Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: I get the HTML tags after being transformed from jstl tags in the tag element subCategoryID instead of receiving JSON object